# For..Next not working with dataset column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
'validatation begin
'Validate User ID 
Private Sub txtUid_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtUid.LostFocus
    Try
        Dim sel As String
        sel = "SELECT uid FROM user_master"
        Dim cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RSMS_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sel, cnn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)
        Dim count As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("uid") = txtUid.Text Then
                ErrorProviderUidExist.SetError(txtUid, "User ID already exists! Please Try a Unique User ID!")
            Else
                ErrorProviderUidExist.SetError(txtUid, "")
                ErrorProviderUidExist.Clear()
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Database Failure!")
    End Try
    If txtUid.Text = Nothing Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtUid, "User ID Required!")
    Else
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtUid, "")
        ErrorProvider1.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

I wrote this code in vb.net to generate a warning using error provider. It generates a warning if the user inputs a user id is already taken. 
In the database, i have created three user ids, 1, 2 and 3.

My problem is when I input 1 while testing, it generates the error, but not when I enter 2 or 3.

Comment: As the documentation clearly states, an application should not be handling the `LostFocus` event. `Leave` is the correct event to handle in that case.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is only going to work if it matches the last row. That's because, if you find a match, you keep on testing the remaining rows and they won't match, so you will clear the error message you previously set. What you need to do is stop when you find a match. That's what `Exit For` is for.